# Can't get Set-Cookie header from http response

Tags: java, cookies, http-headers, web-scraping, response-headers

I am developing a small web content **scraper** . Part of the code is to send a http request and get the cookie from the response header, so it can be set in the subsequent request.
The code to get the cookies is like this:

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    request.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");

    request.setHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");

    if(cookie!=null)
    {
      request.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
    }
         
    request.setHeader("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6");    
    request.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    request.setHeader("Connetion", "keep-alive");
    request.setHeader("Host", "www.booking.com");
    request.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
           AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
           Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36");
    
    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(statusCode);
        //get all headers       
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
                  + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
        }
     
    

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The url I used to test is http://www.booking.com/hotel/il/herods-hotels-spa.html#tab-reviews

The result printed is like this:

```
200

Key : Server ,Value : nginx

Key : Date ,Value : Mon, 03 Feb 2014 05:15:41 GMT

Key : Content-Type ,Value : text/html; charset=UTF-8

Key : Connection ,Value : keep-alive

Key : Cache-Control ,Value : private

Key : Vary ,Value : User-Agent, Accept-Encoding

Key : Set-Cookie ,Value : bkng=11UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YdMHS7ByVcpJ6zdHwCKMHsY37i1DyVPCutMoSY%2F9OR7ixF74JFUj1%2BJ3pF8ntbVX55kLQJvNnfE6Qco2NDwnHPzomws7z40vIxLRgwBTWU9CTbAN3zZqJGksaPN3GqHpSWJ%2BMIKlI5hQN6ZcJnKsU3rR9KXmRVS4plyPQf4gqmsjR131%2BtuuBiULzmDsKzejJZg%2BFgWWUOWS71bCxUGvJbeBBo1HRmUVmigKDEyHylYplnhKkriMof25dYccWyLQoBjIyUL4QZWr58O5D7fKPHDYWSY9y7k%2Bxfk7irIsyKdu%2B0owjpGp2%2BncNdphtqPZqdpeCyky1ReSjWVQ4QuZemceNGmfZGwxm%2BQxu0%2BkBEsJA5zY%2BoqulR8MJIBKZpFqsuvbeDZ9r5UJzl5c%2Fqk7Vw5YU1I%2FQunbw7PHra7IaGp6%2BmHnH2%2BeyiMDhAjWL769ebuwG2DhrgfB6eI0AGZE%2F6T0uA4j7bxA%2FwUdhog6yOu%2FSeTkPl%2FTAiIetVyKLfT1949ggWKfk1kGzmjnowOlZzPbxr1L%2FAifBjInWZ6DreY1Mr2A3%2BfjFYaHJYnS8VpB%2BZappBpGXBUVfHe%2FQ7lbDwNd6TCCzigpsb17LtvFYsb3JiZ%2BQFF82ILNwWFKz6B1xxEEbCRVoq8N%2FcXXPStyGSwApHZz%2Bew6LNI7Hkd2rjB1w3HenUXprZWR3XiWIWYyhMAbkaFbiQV2LThkl2Dkl%2FA%3D; domain=.booking.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 02-Feb-2019 05:15:41 GMT; HTTPOnly

Key : X-Recruiting ,Value : Like HTTP headers? Come write ours: booking.com/jobs
```

However when I uploaded this small program to my server, and ran it, the result became:

```
200

Key : Server ,Value : nginx

Key : Date ,Value : Mon, 03 Feb 2014 05:14:14 GMT

Key : Content-Type ,Value : text/html; charset=UTF-8

Key : Connection ,Value : keep-alive

Key : Cache-Control ,Value : private

Key : Vary ,Value : User-Agent, Accept-Encoding

Key : X-Recruiting ,Value : Like HTTP headers? Come write ours: booking.com/jobs
```

The Set-Cookie header disappeared and my subsequent requests to other content pages within the same site(which are supposed to be loaded by a `javascript` in the first page I requested) all returned 400 error which I guess is because the cookie missing.
I can't figure out why, and the differences between my pc and the server that I know are:

1. My pc is running Windows 7 and actually has a Chrome browser, while the server is running Linux and doesn't have any actual browser.
2. The ip addresses are different.
   Other than these, I can't think of any yet.

Any suggestion or advice to solve this problem will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question with HTTP requests which were actually sent. I think there is some difference between what you want to send and what actually sent. You can catch the requests using some tools like ngrep or fiddler.

Comment: @Majid L Since I was using a cloud server, so there is no way to get the "actual" HTTP requests the server sent out. fiddler will only get the requests sent by the virtual server, and the request is exactly what I included in the question.

Comment: usernameTaken it wasn't me it was @npcode :)

Answer (score 1):

`set-cookie` is a forbidden response header name, you can't read it using browser-side JavaScript

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

> Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set Cookie header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines Set-Cookie as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.